# Stability types in a homogeneous linear system

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

I would like to calculate the range of values for which x<sup>*</sup> (fixed point) = 0 and I want to investigate the type of stability.

$$ \frac{d}{du} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}-5&a\\2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

I have already satisfied the cases for node and saddle.

I want to find the solution for a focus:

From my understanding:

Focus = eigenvalues which are complex conjugate numbers with a positive real part.

In my solution I have obtained that the eigenvalues are:

$-2 \pm \sqrt{9+2a}$

However I am unsure of how to satisfy the values for which the stability point is a focus.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: For a Focus (sometimes called spiral point), don't you just have to find when the eigenvalues are complex-conjugate? The focus is stable when the eigenvalues have negative real part and unstable when they have positive real part. So, when is $9 + 2 a < 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Moo pointed out you need to have complex conjugate eigenvalues. That implies that the expression under the square root has to be negative. Hence,

$$9+2a<0 \implies a<-9/2 \implies a < -4.5.$$

In this case, your eigenvalues will be

$$\lambda_{1/2}=-2\pm i\,\sqrt{|2a+9|}$$

which corresponds to a stable focus.

Comment: Weird, there seems to be a bug in the @ feature as I no longer receive an inbox message from it, (+1).

Comment: @Moo did you receive mine ? +1

Comment: @Isham: Yes I did, on comments, inbox messages seem to work fine.

Comment: I thought so...@Moo the problem occurs only in answers not in comments

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I have given you both +1.